# need help to understand ansible j2

Tags: apache-kafka, ansible

I need help to understand below code for `kafka.properties.j2`.

```
{% for server in kafka_group %}
{% if server.host is defined %}
{% if server.host == inventory_hostname %}
broker.id={{ server.id }}
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://{{ hostvars.get(server).ansible_host }}:{{ kafka_plaintext_port }}
listeners=PLAINTEXT://{{ hostvars.get(server).ansible_host }}:{{ kafka_plaintext_port }}
{% endif %}
{% else %}
{% if server == inventory_hostname %}
broker.id={{ loop.index }}
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://{{ hostvars.get(server).ansible_host }}:{{ kafka_plaintext_port }}
listeners=PLAINTEXT://{{ hostvars.get(server).ansible_host }}:{{ kafka_plaintext_port }}
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

after running above code through Ansible-playbook, it configured `kafka.properties` file like below.

```
broker.id=1
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://54.154.254.129:3997
listeners=PLAINTEXT://54.154.254.129:3997
```

in .ini file below is the entry for kafka group.

```
testdev01 ansible_host=54.154.254.129 ansible_user=ec2-user

[kafka]
testdev01

kafka_ip =172.40.0.20
```

the problem i faced is in `kafka.properties` 3997 got bind to public ip and kafka service was unable to start. after changing it to kafka_ip (172.40.0.20:3997) service started correctly therefore i need to understand. 
whether first `if server.host` part got true or `if server`. 
what is difference between `if server.host ==` and `if server ==` above. 
how it chosen `server.id` as 1, therefore `broker.id=1` came into file. 
why this variable `hostvars.get(server).ansible_host` choose `54.154.254.129` and not `kafka_ip` i.e private ip.

playbook gave below error while listing of Kafka Topics.

```
fatal: [testdev01]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": ["/opt/kafka/kafka_2.12-2.2.2/bin/kafka-topics.sh", "--zookeeper", "54.154.254.129:5181", "--list"], "delta": "0:00:31.730705", "end": "2020-11-28 12:29:52.207646", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2020-11-28 12:29:20.476941", "stderr": "[2020-11-28 12:29:51,779] WARN Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 30007ms for sessionid 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)\nException in thread \"main\" kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING\n\tat kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.$anonfun$waitUntilConnected$3(ZooKeeperClient.scala:242)\n\tat scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)\n\tat kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:251)\n\tat kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:238)\n\tat kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:96)\n\tat kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1825)\n\tat kafka.admin.TopicCommand$ZookeeperTopicService$.apply(TopicCommand.scala:262)\n\tat kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:53)\n\tat kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)", "stderr_lines": ["[2020-11-28 12:29:51,779] WARN Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 30007ms for sessionid 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)", "Exception in thread \"main\" kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING", "\tat kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.$anonfun$waitUntilConnected$3(ZooKeeperClient.scala:242)", "\tat scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)", "\tat kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:251)", "\tat kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:238)", "\tat kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:96)", "\tat kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1825)", "\tat kafka.admin.TopicCommand$ZookeeperTopicService$.apply(TopicCommand.scala:262)", "\tat kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:53)", "\tat kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

`kafka.log` error

```
[2020-11-28 12:29:20,687] ERROR [KafkaServer id=1] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.
KafkaServer)
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Socket server failed to bind to 54.154.254.129:3997: Cannot assign requested address.
        at kafka.network.Acceptor.openServerSocket(SocketServer.scala:573)
        at kafka.network.Acceptor.<init>(SocketServer.scala:451)
        at kafka.network.SocketServer.createAcceptor(SocketServer.scala:245)
        at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors$1(SocketServer.scala:215)
        at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors$1$adapted(SocketServer.scala:214)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at kafka.network.SocketServer.createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors(SocketServer.scala:214)
        at kafka.network.SocketServer.startup(SocketServer.scala:114)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:253)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:38)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:75)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67)
        at kafka.network.Acceptor.openServerSocket(SocketServer.scala:569)
        ... 13 more

[2020-11-28 12:29:20,690] INFO [KafkaServer id=1] shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2020-11-28 12:29:20,692] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1] Stopping socket server request processors (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2020-11-28 12:29:20,695] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1] Stopped socket server request processors (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2020-11-28 12:29:20,699] INFO Shutting down. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2020-11-28 12:29:20,732] INFO Shutdown complete. (kafka.log.LogManager)
```

Comment: The only reference I see to `kafka_ip` in your question is in the inventory and in your question text; why would you presume that `ansible_host` would suddenly take on the value of the hostvar `kafka_ip`? I am not understanding the disconnect in order to help you

Comment: Hi @mdaniel, can you please help to reply on other q. i.e excluding the last one. thanks.

Comment: What was the exact error when Kafka failed to start?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, edited q with kafka.log for error.

Comment: I think the issue is that the port number is so low and you've maybe not used sudo permissions? The IP shouldn't matter

Comment: Otherwise, generally, listeners should be `{PROTOCOL}://0.0.0.0:{PORT}`... Then you would use firewall controls to prevent/allow access. Otherwise, assigning a single IP, you're only binding and allowing connections to that address. In other words, advertised listeners, and listeners should not the same